# Cannot use hyperref with polyglossia on IEEEtran document class--simultaneously!

Tags: xetex, hyperref, ieeetran, polyglossia

The following code runs without problems using `XeLaTeX`. I use `polyglossia` to be able to write Arabic. But when I use `hyperref` I get this error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`. in the line of the `\maketitle` line so that I have commented the lines when `hyperref` is used.

However, If when I remove `\maketitle` everything works :(

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\title{TITLE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\href{www.google.com}{Google Link}

\end{document}
```

I want to use `hyperref` and `polyglossia` in an `IEEEtran` document.

Comment: Interesting... If you load `hyperref` after `\setotherlanguage{arabic}`, the `bidi` package complains that you loaded `hyperref` too late, otherwise you get the error mentioned in the question. Looks like an incompatibility between `hyperref`, `polyglossia`, and `IEEEtran`.

Comment: Is there any alternative instead of`hyperref`?!

Comment: @Taha Not that I know of, and if there are, probably not with the same features. But the answer to the post Alan Munn linked solves your problem.

Comment: @Alan This is helpful